# NavigationService not navigating, async related?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, async-await, navigationservice

Ok I have the following in a wp7 app. I am using Microsoft.Bcl and Microsoft.Bcl.Async.

```
async void FB_Login()
{
   Bool LoggedIn = false;

   LoggedIn = await LoginToFB();

   if(LoggedIn)
   {
      SaveProfile();

      NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));   // Code does reach this point but does not navigate

      MessageBox.Show("Navigating");   // Code does not reach here
   }
}
```

I put break points in at `if(LoggedIn)` and at `NavigationService.Navigate` just to see if it reaches there and it does but the `MessageBox` in the code does not show and putting in a breakpoint does not break indicating its not reaching that far. I also put in a break point in `RootFrame_Navigating` and it doesn't reach there either.

Any ideas as to why its getting stuck at Navigate?

Edit: Problem solved

I put the navigation in a `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` and now it works.

```
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
   NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to extract navigate logic from this method.

Comment: Your comment gave me a light bulb moment :-)